# utilizar el metod getSupportFragmentManager() en un fragment

Tags: android

Quiero que mi dialogfragment se ejecute en un fragmento tengo el siguiente codigo pero me marca error en getSupportFragmentManager ()

ya intente ponerle un getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() pero medice que mi aplicacion se detuvo ne cesito ayuda soy nuevo.

```html
 
 actividad DialogSinglePickerFragment

public class DialogSinglePickerFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private static final int UNSELECTED = -1;
    private static final String ARG_SELECTED = "ARG_SELECTED";
    private static final String ARG_ITEMS = "ARG_ITEMS";
    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "ARG_TITLE";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED = "STATE_SELECTED";

    private DialogPickerFragmentListener listener;

    private int selected;

    public static DialogSinglePickerFragment newInstance(Integer selection, String[] items, String title) {
        DialogSinglePickerFragment fragment = new DialogSinglePickerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if (selection != null) {
            args.putInt(ARG_SELECTED, selection);
        }
        args.putStringArray(ARG_ITEMS, items);
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            listener = (DialogPickerFragmentListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement DialogSinglePickerFragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { //rotation
            selected = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED, UNSELECTED);
        } else if (getArguments() != null) {
            selected = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SELECTED, UNSELECTED);
        }

        final String[] brands = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_ITEMS);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        builder.setTitle(getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE))
                .setSingleChoiceItems(brands, selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selected = which;
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (selected != UNSELECTED) {
                            listener.getSelected(brands[selected]);
                            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), brands[selected], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED, selected);
    }

}
```

```html
public interface DialogPickerFragmentListener {

    void getSelected(String selected);
}
```

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Activity_f1_1 extends Fragment implements DialogPickerFragmentListener {

    private EditText textView;
    private String[] brands;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Activity_f1_1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

   
    public static Activity_f1_1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Activity_f1_1 fragment = new Activity_f1_1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_f1_1, container, false);
        
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.ed_hotel_f1);
        
        setupButtons();
        return view;
    }

    private void setupButtons() {
        textView.findViewById(R.id.ed_hotel_f1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogSinglePickerFragment dialogFragment = DialogSinglePickerFragment.newInstance(4, brands, getString(R.string.hoteles));
                dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),DialogSinglePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void getSelected(String selected) {
        textView.setText(selected);
    }



    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que me marca de error

Comment: Hola, podrias añadir detalles del error que da el depurador y asi sera mas facil resolver el problema :D

Comment: Como comenta @LcsGrz , acostumbra en tus preguntas incluir el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat, saludos!

Comment: Es no marca un error corre bien en el emulador solo cuando quiero activar en onclick me dice que la aplicacion se detuvo

Comment: Gracias, He visto el error , @luissantosmanceras estas usando "import android.app.FragmentManager;" ? o "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;" ?

Comment: estoy usando import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Ya ví cual es el problema, no estas usando el DialogFragment del SDK estas usando una clase llamada .DialogSinglePickerFragment por lo tanto el constructor es diferente, permiteme revisar.

Comment: SI POR FAVOR, se lo agradeceria

Comment: La Activity que abrirá el diálogo debe extender de AppCompatActivity (NO Fragment) e implementar la Interface DialogPickerFragmentListener  , Revisa la respuesta @luissantosmanceras

Answer (score 0):

Si usas DialogFragment el problema se debe al contexto que defines.

Si usas la support library

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

usa :  `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` de esta forma:

```
dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),DialogSinglePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

---

Pero si usas el import:

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

debes usar: `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` :

```
    dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),DialogSinglePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

---

**Actualización:**

En realidad no estas usando `DialogFragment`  estas usando `DialogSinglePickerFragment` por lo tanto tienes que realizar estos cambios.

Primeramente crea la Interface `DialogPickerFragmentListener` :

```
public interface DialogPickerFragmentListener {

    void getSelected(String selected);
}
```

**La `Activity` que abrirá el diálogo debe extender de `AppCompatActivity`  e implementar la Interface `DialogPickerFragmentListener`** :

```
public class Activity_f1_1 extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogPickerFragmentListener {
```

esto te obligará a sobrescribir el método:

```
@Override
public void getSelected(String selected) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

ahora para llamar el Dialogo esta es la forma correcta:

```
DialogSinglePickerFragment dialogFragment = DialogSinglePickerFragment.newInstance(4, brands, getString(R.string.hoteles));
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),DialogSinglePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]